# How to remove only one form autocomplete value

Tags: firefox, autocomplete

My Firefox has managed to save my email address with a typo. So now, when I fill in a form with an email field, I always have to choose between my real email address and the one with a typo. I've found several guides to how to remove all saved form autocomplete values in Firefox, but can't seem to find out how to only remove that entry.

As I don't want to loose all my other saved values, how can I remove only the entry with the typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a late answer but I just had the same issue and figured it out. If you click on the form entry field and the suggest list shows up you can down-arrow to highlight the entry you want to remove. Then use `<shift>-<delete>` and that removes just the one. Hope this helps. Worked with Firefox version 85.0.2 on MacOS.

Comment: Late, indeed. I switched to Brave a while back. Thanks for answering though!